# Getting tasks and related users sql (Codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two mysql tables, named "n_todolist" (to insert there all the task related information), and "n_todolist_users" to asociate specific users id's to every task when needed.

Structures:

- n_todolist: "ID", "groupid", "taskinfo", "state".
- n_todolist_users: "ID", "taskid", "userid".

The way it works is when you add a new task, it gives you the posibiliy of tagging (or not) certain users, here's an example:

- n_todolist: "12", "Take kids to school", "pending"
- n_todolist_users: "1", "12", "10" (where 10 is the userid of someone)

I'm having troubles with getting to show the task info and the user or users tagged on it.

Here's the code i'm using and it works to show only the tasks (I need to show also the users tagged):

```
public function get_todoitems($id){
    return $this->db->
        where("n_todolist.groupid", $id)->
        select("n_todolist.ID, n_todolist.task, n_todolist.state")->
        get("n_todolist");
}
```

Any help is welcome! thanks in advance

Comment: Incidentally, ID in the second table appears to serve no purpose; an entirely valid natural key can be formed on the remaining columns without recourse to a surrogate